# AJAX autocomplete

Tags: ajax

I am trying to implement an auto-complete text field:

```
hook_menu()
{
  $items['products/autocomplete'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'json_list_products',
    'access arguments' => array('access products')
  );

  return $items;
}
```

This appears to work but when I access the *products/autocomplete* I see the resulting JSON data but it's embedded in the HTML template?!?! This is going to cause part of my problem

I am generating the form like so:

```
function form_search_products($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['keyword'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#description' => 'Enter keywords (ie: Fat free milk)',
    '#autocomplete_path' => 'products/autocomplete' 
  );  

  return $form;
}
```

And finally the json query function:

```
function json_list_products() {

  $keywords = 'fat free milk';   // TODO: Swap keywords from parameter list from HTML on client

  $items = array();
  foreach(_sql_select_products($keywords) as $product) {
    $items[$product['Product_ID']] = $product['Product_Name'];
  }    

  return drupal_json_encode($items);
}
```

Anyway, nothing seems to happen...i've managed to do this before so I am not sure why this isn't working now. Any ideas? json_list_products() currently hardcodes the keywords and the results are correct.

Alex

Comment: posting the json_list_products function will help

Comment: Replace `return` with `print` in your Ajax callback and it'll start working

Comment: That solved the JSON being exclusively returned but the input still doesn't show any sign of auto-complete :(

Comment: The little circle in the textfield isn't showing up for some reason so I know something is still a miss :s

Answer (score 1):

```
function modulename_menu() {
  $items['products/autocomplete'] = array(
  'page callback' => 'json_list_products',
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
 return $items;
}

function form_search_products($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = array();

  $form['keyword'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#description' => 'Enter keywords (ie: Fat free milk)',
  '#autocomplete_path' => 'products/autocomplete' 
  );  

  $form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'Save',
  );

  return $form;
}




function json_list_products($string) {
  $matches = array();

  // DB table which holds products
  $query = db_select('products', 'p');

  // Select rows that match the string
  $return = $query
  ->fields('p', array('product'))
  ->condition('p.product', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE')
  ->range(0, 10)
  ->execute();

  // add matches to $matches
  foreach ($return as $row) {
    $matches[$row->product] = check_plain($row->product);
  }

  drupal_json_output($matches);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your hook_menu you need to set the type to menu_callback as the default is MENU_NORMAL_ITEM.

```
hook_menu()
{
  $items['products/autocomplete'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'json_list_products',
    'access arguments' => array('access products'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Also, you may want to use the drupal_json_output function instead of drupal_json_encode in your json_list_products function. the drupal_json_outpur set the correct header.

Also make sure you have the access products permission set correctly.

Not sure if these things will fix your problem, but it's all I can see.

Comment: Check, check and check none worked...I gave up and moved to a Twitter typeahead. Not sure how I close this but now i'm having different drupal issues :p thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I try this one. You must try this

```
hook_menu()
    {
     $items['products'] = array(            //say you have a menu 
     'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
     'page arguments' => array('form_search_products'),
     'access arguments' => array('access products')
      );


      $items['products/autocomplete'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'json_list_products',
        'access arguments' => array('access products')
      );

      return $items;
    }


 function form_search_products($form, &$form_state){

  $form['keyword'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#description' => 'Enter keywords (ie: Fat free milk)',
    '#autocomplete_path' => 'products/autocomplete' 
  );  

  return $form;
    }


function json_list_products($enteredstring){

$yourvalue = $enteredstring;

  $result = db_select('products', 'c')
    ->fields('c')
    ->condition('productname','%'.db_like($yourvalue) . '%', 'LIKE')
    ->orderby('productname')
    ->execute();
}

  $items= array();
  foreach ($result as $items) {
   $title=$items->title;
   $items[$title]=$title;
  }
drupal_json_output($items);

  }
```

It works well.